# Is a Trezor hardware wallet dependent on wallet.trezor.io?

Tags: trezor, hardware-wallet

A [review of the Trezor](https://coincentral.com/trezor-wallet-review/) hardware wallet says:

> In order to access your coins, you would simply do so by connecting your TREZOR to your computer and power up the TREZOR wallet interface at https://wallet.trezor.io. From here, you can see your balances, generate addresses for payment, and send payments.

If trezor.io disappears for any reason, is the Trezor hardware device useless? Are there other ways to spend cryptocoins tied to the private key in the Trezor that don't depend on trezor.io?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a Trezor is not dependent on trezor.io or SatoshiLabs still existing. You can use a Trezor with any wallet software that has implemented support for Trezors. One such wallet is Electrum.

Comment: You may want to update this answer to mention other software that can use Trezors meanwhile. :)